# Como percorrer uma pasta sem saber o nome no PHP

Tags: php

Olá, preciso da ajuda de vocês, eu estou fazendo um sistema bem complexo (para variar) que em uma das partes deste sistema, tem que entrar em uma pasta, porém, esta pasta terá nome indefinido ou seja, **o sistema terá que encontrar o que não foi definido, em simplificação: Meu sistema precisa percorrer em uma pasta, mesmo não sabendo o seu nome, já que a maioria das funções que uso, precisam do nome da pasta, bem e para aqueles que acham fácil isto, saibam que neste sistema, ele usara apenas funções que não se conectam com um banco de dados.
Agora irei dar exemplos sobre isto**:

```
fopen("vaidarerrado/(PASTA NÃO DEFINIDA)/index.php","r");
```

*Caso observem, a função "fopen" irá percorrer a pasta "vaidarerrado", tudo certo, ate que quando chega em algo indefinido que no caso marquei como: "(PASTA NÃO DEFINIDA)", que no caso, obviamente dá um enorme erro, pois, como uma função pode percorrer uma pasta, que nem mesmo o programador informou?, **(alias o sistema quer passar da "(PASTA NÃO DEFINIDA)" pois tem o objetivo de acessar o arquivo "index.php" mesmo sem saber em qual pasta ele está)** ,em mais uma simplificação: percorrer uma pasta sem saber o nome para encontrar um arquivo em especifico, e o única função que eu sei, que pega ALGUMA informação de uma pasta não determinada, e a função*:

```
glob();
```

EXEMPLO:

```
count(glob("vaidarerrado/{*}",GLOB_BRACE));
```

**o código "glob" acima, mesmo sem saber o nome da pasta, consegue "saber de sua existência" e dar o número de coisas que tem no diretório "vaidarerrado", claro, isso apenas foi um exemplo, o que eu quero, e percorrer uma pasta sem saber o nome dela, para encontrar um arquivo, ou se puder, informar o nome da pasta.** 
Espero que me ajudem ou a chegar ao "Index.php" PASSANDO PELA PASTA INDEFINIDA ou de alguma forma, conseguindo pegar o nome da pasta, boa sorte a vocês, espero alguma resposta ;p (kk)

Comment: Por quê não usa a função `glob` se ela faz o que você precisa?

Comment: a resposta está na própria pergunta... normalmente usa-se o glob() ou equivalentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considere a seguinte estrutura de arquivos:

```
 pasta/
     d46as54d9as/
         index.php
```

Com a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php), só lendo o básico da documentação, podemos fazer:

```
foreach (glob("pasta/*/index.php") as $file)
{
    echo $file;
}
```

O retorno será:

```
pasta/d46as54d9as/index.php
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, porém, antes mesmo de você faze-la, percebi que a função count() era para arrays, então acabei de perceber que o glob() também retornava um arrays de algo, porém eu pensava que era apenas números, então resolvi ver o que tinha nestes arrays, ate de surpresa, achar o que tanto queria, praticamente... minha pergunta já foi a própria resposta, mas agradeço seu esforço! (ou nem esforço, quem sabe...)

Comment: Por isso que eu disse antes: bastava estudar um pouco mais.